# System Query Exception: Aggregate Query

Tags: apex, trigger, count

I am getting the following error for my contact count trigger below. I am not sure what this error means. It only affects 2 out of 300,000+ accounts in my org.

> Error: Invalid Data. 
>   Review all error messages below to correct your data.
>   Apex trigger NumberOfContacts caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: NumberOfContacts: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.QueryException: Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop: External entry point

```
trigger NumberOfContacts on Account (before insert, before update) {
    if(trigger.isinsert)
        for(account a:trigger.new)
            a.Number_of_contacts__c = 0;
    else
        for(account a:[select id,(select id from contacts) from account where id in :trigger.new])
            trigger.newmap.get(a.id).Number_of_contacts__c = a.contacts.size();

        for(account b:[select id,(select id from contacts where Inactive__c = False) from account where id in :trigger.new])
            trigger.newmap.get(b.id).Number_of_active_contacts__c = b.contacts.size();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the big gotchas of using Parent-Child subqueries (a.k.a a Left Outer Join from [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com))

If there are enough child records (limit seems to be around 250), Salesforce won't allow you to access the list of child records without using a for loop.

The basic version of this workaround is

```
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account LIMIT 10];

Map<Id, List<Contact>> accountToContacts = new Map<Id, List<Contact>>();

for(Account acct :accounts){
    accountToContacts.put(acct.Id, new List<Contact>());

    // Instead of using acct.Contacts.size(), or contactList = acct.Contacts
    //   we need to use a loop to go through the child records one by one
    for(Contact cont :acct.Contacts){
        accountToContacts.get(acct.Id).add(cont);
    }

}
```

Since you'll need to loop over every related `Contact`, I don't think there's a benefit to maintaining two separate queries to get the total number of `Contacts` and the number of active `Contacts`. I'd include the `Inactive__c` field in your query, initialize another `Map<Id, List<Contact>>`, and then have an `if` inside the loop over contacts to put only the active ones into one of your maps.

After you've satisfied Salesforce's whims, you'll need to loop over your `Accounts` to actually get the counts.

```
// Assuming before update
for(Account acct :trigger.new){
    acct.Number_of_Active_Contacts__c = accountActiveContacts.get(acct.Id).size();
    // and a very similar line for setting the total number of contacts

}
```

Comment: It also seems to be dependent on API version; I recently saw a question where they were able to have up to 10,000 child items without getting that error.